# How can we generate a specific (non periodic) digital signal in Multisim?

Tags: multisim

Could someone please tell me how to generate a specific digital signal in Multisim ,other than the ones provided by the function generator , like this one for example : [image]

I've tried to use the word generator but it was unsucessful.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there a feature in multisim to take the contents of an ascii file and use that as a "user defined" signal source?

Comment: @Andy aka there is no such option to my knowledge.

Comment: Some tools have PWL, where the human provides tuples of (time, voltage) or perhaps (voltage,time).